# WP Ajax never returning any data / calling action

Tags: ajax

I have a simple click function that gets the data of a radio button in a form and passes it to a function in my functions.php file. The problem is the Ajax never calls my action in my functions.php file. I always get "nothing found" as set in my ajax function.

Here is my code below, if anyone can spot the problem would be greatly appreciated.

JS:

```
$(".faq-category-select").on("click",function() {

var faqCategory = $(this).attr('value');
var str = '&faq_category=' + faqCategory + '&action=load_faqs_by_category';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: ajax_params.ajaxurl,
    data: str,
    success: function(data) {
        var $data = $(data);
        if($data.length){
            $("#faq-archive-content-wrap").append($data);
        } else{
            $("#faq-archive-content-wrap").append('<p>nothing found</p>');
        }
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
    }

});
return false;

});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" id="faq-filter-form" method="post">

<h3>Heading 1</h3>

<input type="radio" name="faq-category-select" class="faq-category-select" value="value 1"><label>Value 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="faq-category-select" class="faq-category-select" value="Value 2"><label>Value 2</label>

<h3>Heading 2</h3>

<input type="radio" name="faq-category-select" class="faq-category-select" value="value 3"><label>Value 3</label>
<input type="radio" name="faq-category-select" class="faq-category-select" value="value 4"><label>value 4</label>

</form>
```

functions.php

```
 add_action ( 'wp_ajax_load_faqs_by_category', 'load_faqs_by_category' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_faqs_by_category', 'load_faqs_by_category' );

function load_faqs_by_category() {

  $faq_category = (isset($_POST['faq_category'])) ? $_POST['faq_category'] : '';

  header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $output = '';
    $output .= 'you selected the'.$faq_category.'category';

  die($output);

}

wp_register_script( 'faq-ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/faq-ajax.js', '','',true );
wp_localize_script( 'faq-ajax', 'ajax_params', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'faq-ajax' );
```

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log($data)` in your success callback?

Comment: I see you're using the legacy admin AJAX, it's quite difficult to debug when things go wrong, is there a reason you chose this API instead of the modern REST API? A REST API endpoint would have responded with an error message that would state the problem in plain english. Also, is some of your AJAX handler missing? If all it does is print out a parameter from POST then you don't need AJAX to do that

Comment: @mikerojas I just get '0'

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes some of the handler is missing / incomplete. This is just to test that the function is being called so far which it is not. Just to add, the reason I am using this method is just because I have done it this way before. I will look into the other method you mentioned at a later stage.

Comment: The other method works 95% of the same, but has easier debugging, and also does a lot of the handling of things for you. If this were my problem I would find it easier to convert it than to fix it. Otherwise I suspect the problem is in your javascript. I'm also unsure why `die()` is used here or why the header call is necessary

Comment: If your goal is to load posts of type `faq` from a category, you could do that using the REST API that's already there if you specify `show_in_rest` when registering it. Then a quick  `GET` call to yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/faqs/?faq_category=123 would retrieve the posts. You could even visit that URL in the browser